# Apply a general template after each template is processed/evaluated

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Person">
    <xsl:apply-templates select ="/Person/FirstName"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select ="/Person/MiddleName"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select ="/Person/LastName"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select ="/Person/CompanyInfo/CompanyName"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Person/FirstName">
    <FirstName>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </FirstName>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Person/MiddleName">
    <MiddleName>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </MiddleName>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Person/LastName">
    <LastName>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </LastName>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="Person/CompanyInfo/CompanyName">
    <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyName>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </CompanyName>
    </CompanyInfo>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != '' or ./@* != ''">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select = "@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then I have this sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Information>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Person 1</FirstName>
    <MiddleName/>
    <LastName>Last 1</LastName>
    <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyName></CompanyName>
    </CompanyInfo>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Person 2</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Mid 2<MiddleName/>
    <LastName>Last 2</LastName>
    <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyName>CompName 2</CompanyName>
    </CompanyInfo>
  </Person>
</Information>
```

etc..

I need to have an output like this:

```
<Person>
  <FirstName>Person 1</FirstName>
  <LastName>Last 1</LastName>
</Person>
<Person>
  <FirstName>Person 2</FirstName>
  <MiddleName>Mid 2<MiddleName/>
  <LastName>Last 2</LastName>
  <CompanyInfo>
     <CompanyName>CompName 2</CompanyName>
  </CompanyInfo>
</Person>
```

But I think my xslt is not giving me the desired output, what I need is to process each specific template then will still have to process the last identity template which I got here also, please any help :)

What im trying to do here is omit the empty tags upto the root if everything inside is empty, but I have already created several templates that does what I wanted to output except for the empty tags

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the identity transformation template and then add a template preventing copying of those elements you don't want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(node()[normalize-space()])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You need to add

```
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

to get a consistent indentation.

Here is a complete example, when I apply the code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(node()[normalize-space()])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to the corrected input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Information>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Person 1</FirstName>
    <MiddleName/>
    <LastName>Last 1</LastName>
    <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyName></CompanyName>
    </CompanyInfo>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Person 2</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Mid 2</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Last 2</LastName>
    <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyName>CompName 2</CompanyName>
    </CompanyInfo>
  </Person>
</Information>
```

then I get the result

```
<Information>
   <Person>
      <FirstName>Person 1</FirstName>
      <LastName>Last 1</LastName>
   </Person>
   <Person>
      <FirstName>Person 2</FirstName>
      <MiddleName>Mid 2</MiddleName>
      <LastName>Last 2</LastName>
      <CompanyInfo>
         <CompanyName>CompName 2</CompanyName>
      </CompanyInfo>
   </Person>
</Information>
```

If you really don't want a root element for the output then use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(node()[normalize-space()])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

in that case you get a fragment with several `Person` elements:

```
<Person>
   <FirstName>Person 1</FirstName>
   <LastName>Last 1</LastName>
</Person>
<Person>
   <FirstName>Person 2</FirstName>
   <MiddleName>Mid 2</MiddleName>
   <LastName>Last 2</LastName>
   <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyName>CompName 2</CompanyName>
   </CompanyInfo>
</Person>
```

Comment: Hi, its still displays empty tags, and by the way in one XML file there may be multiple instances of Person that is the reason for the templates

Comment: If the real input is more complex than the sample you posted then it is time to show us a representative sample.

Comment: I have edited my post, basically I want to omit empty tags up to the Person level if the Person Data is empty, so I want to retain my templates for each field if possible and process/add a template to omit the empty fields at the end of the transformation :)

Comment: @zyberjock, sorry, but now you have two top level `Person` elements, that is not even well-formed XML as there needs to be a single root element containing all other elements.

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry for that, i edited my post again :)